# What if in a mapping table from with jpa but I omit a table field in the class?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

hello I would like to consult.  What happens if in a table already created previously I try to map it to an entity but I forget to map a field.  What happens to that field in the table and what will its behavior be if I try to use crud methods?

For example , My table has
Id, Name, Age, country but in my class I'm just mapping Id, name, Age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JPA provider will simply ignore unmapped columns: They won't be read, and values for them will be omitted on `INSERT`.

This can actually be useful; if you find yourself frequently needing only a few columns from a large table, you can create a `*View` class (usually with only getters, no setters) that's explicitly mapped to the table and only fetches/exposes those columns.